# Mule secure-property-placeholder maven settings

Tags: maven, security, mule, mule-studio

I would like know the maven config for Mule's secure-property-placeholder (ZIP).

Thanks.

Regards,
Raj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-security-property-placeholder</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And is available from the follwoing repository. You will need a username and password supplied by MuleSoft in order to access the EE repo:

```
<repository>
    <id>mulesoft-ee</id>
    <name>Mulesoft EE</name>
    <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: Currently 1.4 version is available, and soon 1.5 version for Mule 3.7.0 and Java 8.

Comment: Thanks @ Ryan for your quick reply, I am now able to add it.

Comment: @AleSequeira Whats the latest version because i cant find it anywhere -.-

Comment: @MalcolmTanti 1.6.0, but check the version compatibility table: https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/anypoint-enterprise-security-release-notes#version-compatibility

Comment: How this dependency is packages in the Mule deployable archive ? Should it be inside /plugins directory rather than /libs?

Comment: This solution is only for enterprise edition. Any idea if security property placeholder allow to use in community edition?